# Does this phrase make sense here?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, phrases

***When the client feels the invoice isn’t fair enough for the quality of design:**.*

In the above sentence, I used the word **fair** for invoice. Basically I want to say that the client feels the quality of design isn't good and still he has been given an invoice with more charges/bill (sorry I don't know correct word).

I Googled the similar use of fair invoice, but couldn't find satisfactory results. I understand the meaning of fair bill, fair deal, fair commenet/question/answer etc. But I just can't say about this use.

So the *fair enough for* phrase makes sense here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would more likely be said simply "isn't fair", maybe like this:

> The invoice isn't fair given the substandard quality of the design.

You might also just say

> The invoiced amount is excessive for such a low-quality design.

"Not fair enough" doesn't quite work.